# Derive a string replacement

Tags: string, algorithm, replace, grammar

In a lot of languages, there is a function that does something like this:

```
replace(string, pattern, replacement)
replace("aSb", "S", "ba")
  => "abab"
```

But is there any way to write a function that does the opposite?

```
derive_replacement(before_string, after_string)
derive_replacement("space ba ba space ba", "fact ba ba fact ba")
  => ("space", "fact")
```

I realize there are a few ways to do this that will return a rule that gets you from one string to the other, but I am looking for the shortest one. For instance, both of the following will technically work but will not find the shortest string:

```
derive(before, after) {
    return (before, after)
}

derive(before, after) {
    first_diff = len(commonprefix(before, after))
    last_diff = len(commonsuffix(before, after))
    return (before[first_diff:len(before) - last_diff],
        after[first_diff:len(after) - last_diff])
}
```

I am looking for a general way to do this, but if it helps, I am trying to get this to work in Haskell. Any language or even pseudocode will be sufficient, though.

Comment: maybe this one would be helpful. it's an improved levenshtein operations implementation in python. https://rawgit.com/ztane/python-Levenshtein/master/docs/Levenshtein.html

Answer (score 1):

This is not a simple problem.

Your second example will provide wrong results in some cases. Consider what would happen if you called

derive("foo foo foo","foo baz foo").

Obviously a brute force approach is possible e.g. (in c-like psuedocode)

```
if (before==after) return "",""
for (pl=1;pl<(len(before)-1);pl++) {
  for (ps=0;ps<=len(before)-pl;ps++) {
    for (rl=1;rl<len(after)-ps;rl++) {
      pattern=substr(before,ps,pl);
      replacement=substr(after,ps,rl);
      if (replace(before,pattern,replacement) == after) {
        return(pattern,replacement);
      }
    }
  }
}
return (before,after);
```

I do not know if there is any more efficient soloution.

Comment: Good point about the second example, although it does technically work in all the cases I am using this function for. I am trying to find improvements on your solution now, such as the fact that if the second string is empty, the answer will be (before, "").